# How to make a ratio win:total with only integers and least terms

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to show a simple ratio of wins vs total games. For example:

```
2 wins on  5 games would give me a ratio of 2:5
5 wins on 15 games: 1:3
8 wins on 18 games: 4:9
```

As a nice to have, it would fun to allow half points for the first member, but I guess this would be too complicated:

```
7 wins on 10 games: 3.5:5
```

Comment: To avoid decimal points, you can multiply by 10; 7 wins on 10 games: 35:50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you want to simplify the fraction (e.g. 5/15 => 1/3), but there's no standard function for that in Google Spreadsheets.

Some time ago I found [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/gzR7vXdmocM), where a formula is mentioned:

```
=(A2*(10^(LEN(A2)-2)))/GCD(A2*(10^(LEN(A2)-2)) ;10^(LEN(A2)-2))& " / " & ( 10^(LEN(A2)-2)) /GCD(A2*(10^(LEN(A2)-2)) ;10^(LEN(A2)-2))
```

where `A2` is wins divided by games. It does not grant your wish of half points, but you might be able to massage the formula into giving you that.

I set up an example spreadsheet using that formula [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdGhYcUh3cmhDRDJMeEdTakk3dnJjY3c&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 6):

Simplifying fractions can easily be done with the GCD-function (Greatest Common Divisor).
Using this function

```
=A1/GCD(A1;B1) & ":" & B1/GCD(A1;B1)
```

will give you this result:

```
   A   B    C
1  2   5   2:5
2  5  15   1:3
3  8  18   4:9
```

If you really want half points, just multiply all values with two and at the end divide them by two again:

```
=(2*A1/GCD(2*A1;2*B1))/2 & ":" & (2*B1/GCD(2*A1;2*B1))/2
```

However, this will give you results like 0.5:1.5

```
   A   B     C
1  2   5   1:2.5
2  5  15   0.5:1.5
3  8  18   2:4.5
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer